# How can I tell if my internet speed issues are coming from my wireless router or from my ISP?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, isp

For the past couple of months I've been having major internet connection stability issues with my ISP (Charter).

I have their 100Mbps package, but most of the time the speeds are all over the place. For instance, I just got 0.39Mbps down (as in, < 1Mbps) and then right after it got 50Mbps. Many times I do get in the > 80Mbps range, but the speed is just all over the place.

Charter has been out a dozen times and has replace all the wiring from my modem all the way to the pole outside and the modem itself ([Motorla SB6121](http://www.motorola.com/us/consumers/SURFboard-eXtreme-SB6121-DOCSIS-3.0-Cable-Modem/SURFboard%20eXtreme%20SB6121%20DOCSIS%203.0%20Cable%20Modem,en_US,pd.html)) has been replaced a couple of times.

I have an [Airport Extreme](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/) wireless router.

Charter is stumped and I am too. Is there some sort of test I could run to see if the problem could actually be coming from my Airport Extreme?

Comment: connect a cable to the router and test it for speed. if the results is unexplainable odd or similar to wireless, you have a wireless problem.

Comment: Testing from various servers (probably 5-6 different ones). All seem to test about the same (ie. sporadic).

Comment: Can traceroute can be useful for this?

Answer (score 5):

If you hook a single computer right to the modem (eliminating the Airport and all else) is the connection better? If not, it's between the modem and the ISP.   If it Is better, then it's on your side (Airport, interference, your computer's WiFi, etc.)

Since there's a good chance it's your router (routers break, such is life), or something else on your network, I'm surprised your ISP didn't make you try that before replacing all that cable a dozen times. :/

Also see: [Ways to Determine if Internet Dropout is Router or ISP?](https://superuser.com/questions/196632/ways-to-determine-if-internet-dropout-is-router-or-isp?rq=1)

Comment: +1  Would have thought a direct connect would have been first test by ISP.  Always first thing mines asks for.